# aws quicksight create-analysis cli command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

We have two different accounts:

- one for developing
- another clien prod account

We have cloudformation templates to deploy resources, during developing new features firstly we test on dev and then deploy to prod. But with quicksight it not so easy, there are no cloudformation templates for quicksight. We need to reacreate all reports in prod account, manually it is very hard. I found QuickSight API and create-analysis command but I don't understand how I can create analysis via this command.

Maybe someone have examples or know how to create analysis with cli?

Answer (score 4):

Slavik

It's not possible to create an entirely new analysis or dashboard via the API, however it is possible to promote these throughout the environments via the API.  I found the following AWS blog post to be of some use:

[AWS QuickSight Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/evolve-your-analytics-with-amazon-quicksights-new-apis-and-theming-capabilities/)

Rich

Comment: can you help on how to create RDS dataset for quicksight using boto3?

Comment: This answer is outdated and you can achieve it by following this guide: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/quicksight-cross-account-template

Answer (score 1):

First create an Analysis Template using:

```
aws quicksight create-template --aws-account-id 123456789123  --cli-input-json file://./create-template.json
```

You can use the following JSON (create-analysis-cli-input.json):

```
  {
     "AwsAccountId":"123456789123",
     "AnalysisId":"TestAnalysis",
     "Name":"TestAnalysis-Report",
     "Parameters":{
        "StringParameters":[
           {
              "Name":"Parameters1",
              "Values":[
                 "All"
              ]
           },
           {
              "Name":"Parameters2",
              "Values":[
                 "All"
              ]
           }
        ],
        "IntegerParameters":[
           {
              "Name":"IntParameter1",
              "Values":[
                 0
              ]
           },
           {
              "Name":"IntParameter2",
              "Values":[
                 1000
              ]
           }
        ],
        "DateTimeParameters":[
           {
              "Name":"Date1",
              "Values":[
                 20160327
              ]
           },
           {
              "Name":"Date2",
              "Values":[
                 20160723
              ]
           }
        ]
     },
     "Permissions":[
        {
           "Principal":"arn:aws:quicksight:ap-southeast-2:123456789123:user/default/user-qs",
           "Actions":[
              "quicksight:UpdateDataSourcePermissions",
              "quicksight:DescribeDataSource",
              "quicksight:DescribeDataSourcePermissions",
              "quicksight:PassDataSource",
              "quicksight:UpdateDataSource",
              "quicksight:DeleteDataSource"
           ]
        }
     ],
     "SourceEntity":{
        "SourceTemplate":{
           "DataSetReferences":[
              {
                 "DataSetPlaceholder":"Template-SRM-Payments Dataset",
                 "DataSetArn":"arn:aws:quicksight:ap-southeast-2:123456789123:dataset/abc"
              },
              {
                 "DataSetPlaceholder":"Template-SRM-DailyPayments Dataset",
                 "DataSetArn":"arn:aws:quicksight:ap-southeast-2:123456789123:dataset/def"
              },
              {
                 "DataSetPlaceholder":"Template-SRM-DateTable Dataset",
                 "DataSetArn":"arn:aws:quicksight:ap-southeast-2:123456789123:dataset/ghi"
              }
           ],
           "Arn":"arn:aws:quicksight:ap-southeast-2:123456789123:template/report-template"
        }
     },
     "ThemeArn":"arn:aws:quicksight::aws:theme/SEASIDE",
     "Tags":[
        {
           "Key":"Name",
           "Value":"TestReport"
        }
     ]
  }
```

The CLI command to run is:

```
aws quicksight create-analysis --aws-account-id 123456789123 --cli-input-json file://./create-analysis-cli-input.json
```